# People in Turkey voted in / on referendum?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition for voting **in / on** referendum?

For example:

> "People today voted **in / on** referendum in Turkey."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/referendum) defines referendum as follows (note the **on**):

> A general vote by the electorate **on** a single political question which has been referred to them for a direct decision.

The preposition **in** [(meaning 5, Expressing inclusion or involvement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)) is appropriate for participation **in** the referendum. The preposition **on** ([meaning 3, Having  as a topic; about](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on)) is appropriate for the subject of the referendum, as used in the above definition.

You could therefore make a complete sentence like this (I have revised the word order a little):

> People in Turkey voted today **in** a referendum **on** constitutional changes proposed by Recep Tayyip Erdoğan.

Note that referendum is a countable noun, so you have to use an article (**a** or **the**). In this context, you would probably use **a** if you assume that the readers don't know about this particular referendum, and **the** is you assume that they do know about it.

Comment: You should probably *explicitly* make the point that ***referendum*** must be preceded by an article in contexts like this (either ***the*** or ***a*** depending partly on whether the speaker assumes his audience know of the *existence* of such a proposed referendum, regardless of whether they know when it will take place).

Comment: The referendum *is* the subject.

Comment: @EJP: Semantically speaking, it seems to me that "hard Brexit" has been about ***the only subject*** of public discourse in the UK for several months, but it's nearly always ***a** hard Brexit*, not ***the** hard Brexit* even though by now everyone knows what's being referred to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know why you're addressing that remark to me, or indeed to anyone. It doesn't have anything to do with my comment, or my answer, or the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think that EJP is referring to the Latin gerundive origins of the word referendum (that which is referred) rather than to the choice of article.

Answer (score 0):

The referendum is the *subject*: the matter referred to the people. The *process* is called a *plebiscite*. Therefore, the answer is that they voted *in* a plebiscite and *on* a referendum (or on several referenda, if there were multiple questions).

Comment: Can you provide some references to back up your opinion? I agree that referendum sounds like a Latin gerundive, on similar lines to an addendum, but I don't think that it is used in that way in English.

Comment: @JavaLatte Kennedy's Latin Primer.

Comment: I believe that from a pedantic standpoint you're probably correct.  I suspect, however, that in common usage "referendum" has come to refer to the process, rather than just the decision made thereby, in much the way that "podium" has come to refer to a lectern, rather than just the speaking platform (literal or figurative) served thereby.